# opengl rotation texture off center

Tags: java, opengl

I wrote some code to get a plain 2d box to face the mouse. It rotated just fine around its center, and everything was working great, but when i put a texture on the box, it did not rotate around the center anymore.

The code:

```
    float imgWidth = texture.getImageWidth()*scale;
    float imgHeight = texture.getImageHeight()*scale;

    glLoadIdentity();

    texture.bind();

    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glRotated(rotation - 90, 0, 0, 360);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(-imgWidth, -imgHeight);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); 
        glVertex2f(imgWidth, -imgHeight);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-imgWidth, imgHeight);
    glEnd();
```

Comment: So, in this example, if you comment out the call to .Bind(), it works?

What's in .Bind()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple but with a complicated background that has to be understood.

**OpenGL always rotate something not around its center but takes as center the point (0;0).**

This can be an issue because if you translate your object somewhere and then your rotate it, it will rotate not on its center but around the (0;0) point (origin) creating a big rotation, I will say as a planet around the Sun.

Also OpenGL works with matrix, that with very barbaric simplification means that the operation are executed bottom to top.

```
// store the current model matrix
GL11.glPushMatrix();

// bind to the appropriate texture for this image
this.texture.bind();

// translate to the right location and prepare to draw
GL11.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
GL11.glTranslated(x + (this.texture.getImageWidth() / 2), y + (this.texture.getImageHeight() / 2), 0);

GL11.glRotated(this.angle, 0, 0, 1);
GL11.glTranslated(-this.texture.getImageWidth() / 2, -this.texture.getImageHeight() / 2, 0);
    // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, this.texture.getHeight());
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, this.texture.getImageHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(this.texture.getWidth(), this.texture.getHeight());
        GL11.glVertex2f(this.texture.getImageWidth(), this.texture.getImageHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(this.texture.getWidth(), 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(this.texture.getImageWidth(), 0);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();

    // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

This means that first I am moving the texture to have its center positioned at (0;0) that means translating it backward half the dimensions.
Then I rotate it, and this is the crucial point, because you are using a strange way to rotate it, maybe the problem it's here, take a look to the javadoc:

```
  SPECIFICATION
  void glRotated( GLdouble angle,<br>
          GLdouble x,<br>
          GLdouble y,<br>
          GLdouble z )<br>
  void glRotatef( GLfloat angle,<br>
          GLfloat x,<br>
          GLfloat y,<br>
          GLfloat z )<br>


 PARAMETERS<br>
  angle  Specifies the angle of rotation, in degrees.

  x, y, z<br>
     Specify the x, y, and z coordinates of a vector, respectively.

 DESCRIPTION<br>
  glRotate produces a rotation of angle degrees around the<br>
  vector (x,y,z).
```

First of all all x,y,z values should be between 0 and 1, if you want to rotate a 2d image then you should use the z axis, so the third param will be 1 that mean that you are rotating your image around the unit vector z.
The angle should be in degree and can be either positive or negative.

Try to change your code according to the documentation and you will have your problem solved.
Also with your quad you are drawing a 2x scaled quad, you are starting from -imageWidth to +imageWidth that means 2 times the width...